# Set notation of an object that belongs to $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$ space?

Tags: notation

$$((x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}), (...), ...) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $$
$$ \text{?} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$$

The first example is used to denote **vector** space, the second I have seen used to denote **matrix** space.

What would you write instead of the **?** sign, ideally in the form $(...)$?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch What would you write instead of "?" in second expression?

Comment: That depends, do you mean something like $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \\ x_5 & x_6 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I've never encountered the notation $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$. Isn't it equal to $\mathbb{R}^6$? Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^2$? The set of matrices of a set dimension is written $\mathcal{M}_{3,2}(\mathbb{R})$... at least that I use.

Comment: @Wyllich : This is a common notation for the space of $3$ by $2$ matrices over the real numbers.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch Is there a way to write the matrix in a more linear fashion, using commas and tuples?

Comment: @Wyllich I have seen the notation in Wikipedia, Matrix: Notation section (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Notation).

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger Yup. I checked too. Never seen it though... French education...

Comment: @Wyllich Now I am unsure about set notation for the matrix space as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like $(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},x_{31},x_{32})$ if you like, but you can choose whatever indexing scheme when you want to make explicit the components of an element.

Comment: I guess you are right, which in more detail would be $$((x_{11} = f(1,1), x_{12} = f(1,2), x_{21} = f(2,1), ...), (...), ...) \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$$.